# Factorizing multivariate polynomial over finite fields

Tags: python, polynomials, factorization, finite-field

I'm working on a project where I need to factorize a given bivariate polynomial over a finite field, is there any python library that can help me? Sympy cannot factorize multivariate polynomial over a finite field, so is there any other library that can do the job?

Comment: You could have a look at PyPI: https://pypi.org/search/?q=factorize+polynomial

Comment: Can we please have the polynomial (and the characteristic of the field)?! Depending of the submitted data, the way to attack may differ...